# Django: Initialize model add view with data through admin action

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I'm running a photography app in Django. I have a `Photograph` model and a `PhotoSet` model with a `ManyToManyField` relationship to `Photograph`. I would like to create an admin action where I can select several `Photograph` objects in the admin list view, choose the "Create photo set from selected photos" action, and be taken to the `admin:photography_photoset_add` view with the `photos` field pre-populated with the photos I selected on the previous page. I'd then be able to enter the title, slug, and description as needed. Is this flow possible? I haven't been able to find it after quite a bit of searching and the only route I currently know of would be handling all of this myself with custom add views and storage of my selection in session state. Seems messy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this part of the docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#actions-that-provide-intermediate-pages

And this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4924985/202168

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

def create_photoset_from_photos(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    ids = ','.join([str(photo_id) for photo_id in queryset.values_list('id', flat=True)])
    add_photoset_url = '{url}?photos={ids}'.format(url=reverse('admin:photography_photoset_add'), ids=ids)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(add_photoset_url)
```

Comment: Hey, this looks like it might just work. I had seen this hinted at in another stackoverflow question, but they didn't get at the meat of it. Thanks a lot for the info. I'll accept if it goes well!